# I need a script for Google spreadsheet that will copy part of a cells information into a new column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with all the below information in the same cell.  I need a script that will separate the information.

Current format in one cell

```
b1  o 29.26  d 18.53  
b2  o 27.54  d 14.60  
b3  o 25.57  d 10.96  
b4  o 24.37  d 11.48  
b5  o 23.34  d 0  
b6  o 0  d 0  
b7  o 0  d 0
```

I need `b1 o 2926 d 18.53` in its own row and `b1` in its own column and then the `29.26` in the next, followed by `18.53`.

  I need that to happen automatically for each line 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If each "row" in that text block is separated by a newline character, then you can break it into a two-dimensional array like this:

```
// Block of info in 'data'
var dataRows = data.split('\n');
for (var row=0;row<dataRows.length;row++) {
  dataRows[row] = dataRows[row].split(' *');
}

sheet.getRange(1,1,dataRows.length,dataRows[0].length).setValues(dataRows);
```